# How to make one to one relation from one to many relation with dynamic/runtime condition nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following map

```
public class FilmActorMap : ClassMap<FilmActor>
{
    public FilmActorMap()
    {
        Table("film_actor");
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.ActorId, "actor_id")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.FilmId, "film_id");
        Map(x => x.LastUpdate, "last_update");
        References<Actor>(x => x.Actor, "actor_id"); //.Fetch.Join();
    }
}

public class ActorMap : ClassMap<Actor>
{
    public ActorMap()
    {
        BatchSize(100);
        Id(x => x.ActorId, "actor_id");
        Map(x => x.FirstName, "first_name");
        Version(x => x.Version);
    }
}
```

In database i have record for as follows

```
film_actor
**********
film_id | actor_id | last_update
--------------------------------
1       | 100      | x


Actor
*****
actor_id | Version | first_name
-------------------------------
100      | 1       | Antonio
100      | 2       | Antony
```

When the application is launched, user is presented with list of revisions done.

If user chooses

Revision#1: Then on selection of film.Actor, I would like to see the record of Version = 1
i.e  record "100      1        Antonio"

Revision#2: 
record "100   2        Antony"

Revision#3: Although for this this record there is no 3rd revision so I would like to see the latest version i.e.  record "100    2        Antony"

Is there anyway to inject this dynamic condition in nHibernate?
Also I would like to have a different condition to fetch the record in batch mode. i.e

```
SELECT * 
FROM Actor
WHERE (actor_id, Version) in ( SELECT actor_id, Max(Version)
                               FROM Actor
                               WHERE Version <= UserEnteredVersion
                               GROUP BY actor_id)
```

**I do not want to fire the query explicitly instead would like to inject condition to the existing mapping runtime. Is this possible using in Interceptor?**

**Edit#1:**
The application loads the main model through query (this is the only explicit query fired) and all other related models are loaded lazily loaded through UI as and when the user navigate through the tree. So I would like inject the where condition to the Actor reference to fetch me the desired version of the actor runtime so that when the drill down happens it chooses the correct record.

Comment: I'm confused, why wouldn't you just query based on the selected revision? i.e. `SELECT * FROM Actor WHERE Version = selectedVersion`?

Comment: @James: That wont give me record for Revision#3 as mentioned in the question. Ok there is application level version which gets incremented whenever save is done (append only model). That does not increment the version of each record. That means my application data can be of currently in 100th revision/version (because of different edit in elsewhere) and actor_id = 100 is only edited twice. Hope this clear

Comment: yes but there is no "*revision 3*", there are 2 revisions, of which I presume the last entry is the current state. What you appear to have here is a half-baked implementation of [event sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html). Generally what you would do is always load the latest version of the record by replaying all historical events, or load up to a specific revision if that version is specified.

Comment: Show the code you use to load the main model.

Comment: +1 for the event sourcing reference that actually made us to re-look at the design we currently we have. Shall get back to on this once ready

Answer (score 1):

You can still use a normal query. Just order by asked revision (e.g. 3) minus revision and take the first entry.

Comment: I am looking for nhibernate or fluent nhibernate map option and not a query option which I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: Ok, in that case I would point you in the direction of filters. You could specify the entire where clause in a filter and enable it with different parameters on demand.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on filter in your answer?

Comment: Sorry, but I am in a train with a bad connection. You can define a filter and add it in the ActorMap. You can then enable and disable it on demand. This blog post (http://ayende.com/blog/3993/nhibernate-filters) should tell you if filters are the way to go for you.

Comment: +1 for filtering. I shall try the same and give you feedback.